# Is there a glue which holds to glazed porcelain tiles?

Tags: ceramic-tile, adhesive

My shower does not have a cabin, only a curtain. Said curtain tends to wave around while I am in the shower, clinging to my legs and letting water flow outside.

My best idea for a low-cost solution was to sew some Velcro strips to the (textile) curtain. This worked well, until I tried to fasten the hooky strips to the wall. It turns out that none of the glues and double-sided tapes I have at home are strong enough. When I pull on the Velcro, the hooky strip comes off the wall and stays hooked to the fluffy strip on the curtain.

Any ideas for low-cost, non-invasive methods of getting the strips to stick to the wall? I assume that I need a stronger glue - what should I look for? Or is it a fool's errand? I am renting this apartment - I can't drill holes and screw something glue-friendly under the Velcro.

The wall is covered with glazed porcelain tile.

Comment: If the tub is iron or steel, they make curtains with magnets sewn in that stay in place nicely.

Comment: Another thought is a suction cup for the tile that has a eyelet.  A hook could be attached to the curtain, perhaps using the existing Velcro.

Comment: Problem is shower heated air rising as a plume, and being replaced by cooler air around base of curtain. A heavier curtain will not billow. Barring that, leaving a slight gap between wall and curtain on whichever end causes least spillage will minimize problem wo glue, hooks or magnets.

Comment: Come to think of it, sewing some curtain weights to the bottom should limit the billowing problem. Rocks in small cloth satchels are cheap, and work as well as the storebought zinc/lead weights.

Answer (score 3):

If you will first thoroughly wet all the pertinent surfaces, your shower curtain will cling all by itself and greatly reduce the irritating billowing and waving, also the leaks to the outside on both ends.  I just toss handfuls of water everywhere I want the curtain to seal off and stick down.  Good luck-

Comment: I don't "throw" handfuls of water at the wall, but I do carefully wet down the wall then stick the curtain to it. Has worked well for me for years!

Answer (score 1):

They make a liquid nails that is formulated for tile - I just used it to hang soap dish and toilet paper thing on my tiles.  I have no idea what you are trying to do (picture would help) but that answers the title.  You do not want to use any type of silicone for this - you need rigidity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the self-adhesive Velcro? They even do a heavy-duty version; I've used that to stick to shiny surfaces before and it has really got a firm hold.

Don't forget to make sure that the tiles are both clean and dry before you attempt to stick anything to them.

Answer (score 0):

Any glue which adheres to glazed porcelain is going to be hard to remove when you move out.

However, a weighted shower curtain would probably do what you want, is easily installed, easy to use, and won't require a lot of work to prepare.

Here are a few possibilities:    [mid range ($30–60)](http://www.sears.com/shc/s/t_10153_12605?tName=weighted-bottom-shower-curtain.html)        [deluxe version ($120–140)](http://www.accessibleconstruction.com/services/bathrooms/24.html)

Or if you already like your shower curtain, and don't mind spending an hour or two adding weights to it, [here are several ideas](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-keep-cheap-shower-curtains-attacking-6546336.html?cat=30) for hot gluing or sewing weights to it.  I doubt bottlecaps would be near enough mass.  For less than $1.50 you can get a half pound (8 ounces or 0.25 kg) of [washers at Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/p/5-16-in-Zinc-Plated-Steel-Flat-Washers-10-Pack-19831/202704552#.UhcrlE2AUkA).